# Pain all over the body - "over"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm a healthcare provider and I, myself, have used this phrase zillions of times. However, grammatically, I want some clarification on this.

> The pain was all **over** the body - is absolutely fine and accepted. It means the patient suffers from pain everywhere **in** their body.

But why we use **over** here? Over makes better sense in this sentence

> She was painted all **over** her body (in case of body painting). 
>   She has rashes all **over** her body - this makes utter sense to me; she has rashes, on her skin, all over the body. It talks about the surface again!

Should I use this to sound grammatically correct? Just as we use *over* more for **the surface** (all over the place) and not something **inside** (body).

> The pain was **everywhere in** the body OVER The pain was all over the body

Comment: I think it's idiomatic. Have you seen [this definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+over)?

Comment: @helix I certainly know this and thus clarified that the pain is everywhere. But compare *rashes all over the body* and *pain all over the body*. That's what the question is all about. Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Isn't it context dependent? Consider: Rashes appear on the skin, pain can be everywhere, and I *wouldn't* recommend painting inside your body.

Comment: @helix painting inside or pain inside?

Comment: If someone told you that their kids left toys all over their house, I believe that you wouldn't imagine those toys being left outside the house.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I already said that... think about the *surface* and the word *over* will fit there. Toys all over their house - all over the place, the surface. Here, the main concern is *surface* where pain does not happen!

Comment: @MaulikV Hmm, but then why do you interpret the "surface" of the body to be just the outer skin, but the "surface" of a house to include interior floors? To be consistent, you'd have to either say that surface of the body is the skin and surface of the house is the outside walls and roof; or that surface of a house is interior floors and surface of a body is bones, organs, etc.

Comment: @Jay don't we have surface (floor) cleaners? Also platform of kitchen is aplo cleaned with that. Fine surface of platform to add shining. That way.

Comment: @MaulikV Sure, just as premature babies are sometimes treated with "surfactants" -- chemicals that affect the SURFACE of the lungs. Which are inside. It's not inherently absurd to talk about the "surface" of the brain or the kidneys, etc, or even the "inner surface" of body organs. My point being, for either a body or a house, "surface" could mean the outer surface -- skin or outer walls and roof -- or it could refer to inner surfaces, depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much the definition of an idiom: The meaning of the phrase is not the same as the sum of the literal meanings of the individuals words that make it up.

Have you ever said, "Try a different tack?" to a person who was NOT piloting a sailboat?

If you couldn't make it to a party because the roof of your house collapsed, would you tell your friends, "Something came up"? But clearly the actual problem is that something came down.

Etc. One could play that game indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

It's not incorrect if you consider a body as a skeleton with an outer covering of muscles and flesh.  In that sense 'all over the body' is perfectly acceptable using the same definition as per painting and rashes.

However, it's probably best described as something that may be technically grammatically incorrect, but which common usage has rendered as acceptable English.  A similar example would be 'all over the place', which just means everywhere.  If your kids have left their toys all over the place, the toys aren't covering the outer walls - they are inside, mainly on the floor.

You have alternatives if you are uncomfortable with *all over the body*.  Pain is also felt 'all **through** the body', and one 'aches down to one's bones' so maybe just use phrases like that.

Comment: This does not answer my question exactly but no downvoting. Well body is body as a whole and that's why *in the body* is a valid phrase for many things to describe. All over the place - I already said that *over* is used to describe *surface* and here, it fits that way! I'm sorry - *all through the body* sounds unnatural to me. But thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Maybe '... through my/your body' (especially from/to a patient), rather than through _the_ body, but it is used.  And those toys 'all over the place' are in the couch cushions, in kitchen cupboards, in the bath ... not just surface stuff.

Comment: *through the body* reminds me of something spiritual... eternal journey kinda stuff! ;)